# URL doesnt work with HTTPS

Tags: tomcat7

I have an url, and the firewall traffic to the same has been enabled through 8443 port and i configured the Tomcat7 for SSL.

I can access the ddomain with http & port 8080 but when i try the same with https and 8443 it runs for a long time and throws page cannot be displayed error.

I have tried everything available on internet to solve the issue but of no use. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you faffing with 8443? If you're going through NAT or something, can you access the server locally? Have you bound a certificate to the server? With the information posted, it's going to be almost impossible to diagnose whatever issue you're facing.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for ur response. May i know what information u need? yes there is a private certificate bound and the root and intermediate certificates as well.

Comment: Hi Dan, I can acess the server locally with https://Localhost:8443

Comment: Can you access the server using whatever IP address the machine is on? i.e., https://192.168.1.20:8443 - if NOT, then your web server is only listening on the loopback interface. If you CAN, then it's probably a NAT issue

Comment: Yes i can access the server using IP with port 8443. What is NAT issue can you explain and help me resolving it.

Comment: Your firewall isn't configured right

Comment: i can also access the server with URL using port 8080 but not with port 8443

Comment: the firewall resource just informed me that the port 8443 is enabled for SSL handshake on the server. 8443 is enabled for SSL traffic on firewall as informed by the firewall resource.